# Creating a custom installer in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wix, windows-installer

I'm looking to create a Metro style WPF based Installer. The reason is I want animations between UI components, transitions etc.

So the question is, what is the best way to tackle this, Should I just interface with the [windows installer api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc185688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or somehow interface with [Wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/)?

That it requires the .NET framework wouldn't be an issue, since it would also be required to run the application being installed. So I'll just have a bootstrapper to check for it or install.

I've read [Make my own Installer from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302405/make-my-own-installer-from-c) but can you really customize the look and feel of the GUIs from WIX? Can you use Wix as a sort of API maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WiX's Burn bootstrapper engine supports custom UIs. WPF is supported and will install .NET if needed. For example, see the [Microsoft Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27543).