# C# - Make custom installer for wpf application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, installation

I want to make a custom application installer for my wpf application. I want to show licence agreement which user will need to accept to proceed then he needs to enter key. then installation bar will begin.

how to do that?Is there any link which can help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286825/creating-a-custom-installer-in-wpf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [WIX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) or [Wix#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31407/Wix-WixSharp-managed-interface-for-WiX)

Alternatives to WIX would probably be [Nullsoft Installer](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/) or [Installshield](http://www.installshield.com/)